# How to use 'Multiple JavaScript function' on Interactive Grid's attributes in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

blank page showing when I am using multiple JavaScript function on interactive grid's attributes

I have a JS function on interactive grid's attributes, all thing working ok.

```js
//first fuction
function(config) {
    // if there were an option to turn off frozen columns we would do that
    // row header was removed to avoid frozen column but still want multiple select
    config.defaultGridViewOptions = {
        multiple: true,
        selectAll: true
    };
    config.initActions = function(actions) {
        actions.lookup("change-rows-per-page").choices.shift(); // get rid of auto rows per page because that relies on fixed height.
    }
    return config;
}
//here when i add second function like added below my page goes blank
function(config) {
    var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(), // Make a copy of the default toolbar
        editSaveGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind( "actions2" );

    // If the employees detail dialog is going to have a Dialog Save button then the
    // save action cannot be hidden (Toolbar Buttons Save unchecked). But rather
    // need to remove the button from the toolbar.
    // If not going to save then all this code can be removed and the 
    // attribute Toolbar Buttons Save unchecked.
    editSaveGroup.controls.pop(); // remove Save button.
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    return config;


    }
```

I want to add second js function on ig's attributes but when i add second js function the page shows blank page.

Comment: why do you need to use multi js functions? cant you merge your logic in one function?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Initialization code for Interactive Grids works as a callback function which gets executed once the grid is loaded. Its a single JS function.

You have to merge your two functions into a single function as below:

```
function(config) {
    // Make a copy of the default toolbar
    var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(), 
        editSaveGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions2");

    // If the employees detail dialog is going to have a Dialog Save button then the
    // save action cannot be hidden (Toolbar Buttons Save unchecked). But rather
    // need to remove the button from the toolbar.
    // If not going to save then all this code can be removed and the 
    // attribute Toolbar Buttons Save unchecked.
    editSaveGroup.controls.pop(); // remove Save button.
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    // if there were an option to turn off frozen columns we would do that
    // row header was removed to avoid frozen column but still want multiple select
    config.defaultGridViewOptions = {
        multiple: true,
        selectAll: true
    };
    config.initActions = function (actions) {
        actions.lookup("change-rows-per-page").choices.shift();
    }

    return config;
}
```